# Power BI - Finding the data source

Tags: powerbi, datasource

How can I find the data source of my report? I recently changed laptops and moved my report to the new laptop, but I forgot the data source for my report. I used my database as a data source but because I am not sure on the path of the data source I can not refresh my dataset. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the method mentioned by @mkRabbani using the Advanced editor, the simplest way is to

1. click on the "Gear" icon beside the Source Step
2. and it will open a pop-up using which you can identify the existing source and also replace the source to a different one.

Please note that this applies to all data source, not just excel (but with their own customizations)

[image: Data Source in Power BI]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the folder location of your data files, go to Power Query Editor and right click on the table you wants to know the source. Then click the Advance editor option and you will get the source as shown below-

[image]